# SharePoint 2007 Workflow for multiple items

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-enterprise

In SharePoint 2007 what options do we have say if we want to enable an approval workflow on multiple documents not just one? It's for a Doc Lib which will contain approx hundred PDFs where there are a number of which will require sign off from a different set of approvers, say 50 needing approval from xy and 50 needing approval only from z etc wondered what alternative options may exist?

Answer (score 1):

Can you write some more Detail description?

Because we can create SharePoint Designer workflow base on file contains assigner to different users so on which base to assign document different users.
you cannot start workflow multiple items at a time using Out Of Box features. So you create a workflow in Out Of Box or Designer you should create a Event receiver for Workflow Association to start workflow.

Comment: Sure, we have 100 pdf docs in a document library we want the user to be able to select a number of documents at once and be able to have the option notify different approvers to check and  approve those documents